# where can i find influxdb-java version 2.0

Tags: maven, influxdb

i find the page: https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-java, i use influxdb 0.9, the java api is influxdb-java 2.0, in maven.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

but i can not find this version. i can find the lastest is 1.5 version. please tell what can i do, how can i find and download this jar. thank you very much.

Comment: Does not bode well for InfluxDB ...

Comment: The InfluxDB team and the maintainer of influxdb-java are aware of the maven issues and have been working to get them resolved. Follow this GitHub Issue for progress: https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-java/issues/37

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use JitPack until it gets published

https://jitpack.io/#influxdb/influxdb-java/influxdb-java-2.0

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find it in maven repos, you can download the release from github: https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-java/releases/tag/influxdb-java-2.0

Then installing manually on your local maven repo or your nexus/archiva/artifactory.